# How I can filter entries by status in my dataTable?

Tags: jquery, filter, datatables

I need filter my entries in my dataTable but I don't do a function and connect with my database and return results per status button:

```
Pendiente = Slope
En atención = In Attention
Concluido = concluded
Cancelado = Canceled
```

I want this: When press in any status button, filter the current results in the datatable without connect with a database and get data of each status.

[image]

I hope I have explained

Comment: somehow, can you tell me do you use serverside data? if so that every time, the request will be sent to server as well as  database to get data

Comment: I don't use serverside data, just I connect jquery.ajax with php to get my data and put in the table and just do var oTable = $('#tableTickets').dataTable({
                        "bJQueryUI": true,
                        "bRetrieve" : true,
                        "bDestroy" : true,
                        "aaSorting": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
                        "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers"
                    });

Comment: That's great that you can solve this problem,lol

Comment: `just I connect jquery.ajax with php to get my data ` this means you are calling a server. $.ajax behind the scene you are issuing a GET/POST method

Comment: Is correct! I'll try the code below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment that it's kind of easy to fix it, ok. [here](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/multi_filter.html) and [here](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html) are 2 samples that in datatables official website can give you the solutions for it.

Kind of like this:

```
var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
        "oLanguage": {
            "sSearch": "Search all columns:"
        }
    } );

    $("this should be the buttons that you want to bind filter function").click( function () {
        /* Filter on the column (the index) of this element */
        oTable.fnFilter( "this is the status that you want use to filter", $("tfoot input").index(this) );
    } );
```

And just kindly remind that if you have any question about datatables that you can raise it in its' forum. allan maintains the whole project, he will tell you everything.

Comment: Please Paste some expamples. what would if link break in future ? so it's better to paste some examples!!

Comment: Cool, any problem, let me know.

Comment: The problem with these examples is that we need write in an input or add column to my table and put the status name that when I type in input search filter, show just entries of each status. But my client need a buttons :P

Comment: OK, I saw that the rows have different colors, is this means the status? how do you specify the status of each row?

Comment: Yes, each status have different color, and to specify color of each row according with ur status, in my js method I compare a variable of json return like this: if (response.status == 1) row.css("backgroundColor",colorpendiente); ..etc etc

Comment: I see, for this new change that you have to add a new hidden column which is the status to the datatables and then check my edited answer

Comment: Yes, I think is the best solution. I added a hidden column and put name of status in each row and when type name of any status, show only entries containg that status! Thanks!

Comment: that's my pleasure, let's go forward together